# How to embed text in video using flowplayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

There is a video playing in [flowplayer](http://flash.flowplayer.org/) and it is downloadable on my website.

I'm using following code to animate text from right: 100% to left 100% using jquery.

```
 flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
                wmode: 'transparent',
                // the content plugin will show the ad
                plugins: {
                    myContent: {
                        url: 'flowplayer.content-3.2.9.swf',
                        wmode: 'transparent',
                        top: 20,
                        right: '129%',
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        width: '295',
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        padding: 0,
                        background: 'transparent',
                        border: '0px solid transparent',
                        backgroundGradient: 'none',
                        style: {
                            '.title': {
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontFamily: 'verdana,arial,helvetica'
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                clip: {
                    url: 'stepup.mp4',

                    // make something happen on the mid of clip
                    onCuepoint: [[1000 * 60], function(clip, cuepoint) {

                            var plugin = this.getPlugin("myContent");

                            plugin.setHtml('<p>This is sample text</p>');

                            plugin.animate({left: '129%'}, 90000);

                        }],
                }
            });
        });
```

I have two question from following code:

1) How would i set the cue point at mid of the video. Currently it is set to 60th second.

2) How to stop text animation on stop and start on resume.

3) How would I maintain the width of screen for animation from left edge of the video to right edge of video.

4) Will the embedded text in video be existing in the downloaded file? If not how would I?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on adding Captions in a Flow video.

Sample code below:

```
          <p begin = "00:00:00.01" dur="04.00">
        First caption with default style coming from the Content plugin config
    </p>

          <p begin = "00:00:04.19" dur="04.00" style="1">
      2nd caption with timed text styling to make the text white
    </p>

          <p begin = "8s" dur="04.00" style="2">
      3rd caption using a small black font
    </p>
     </div>
```

Here is the address to find the tutorial:

http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/captions.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I already have done this. And This was my question.